# Extracting coefficients and intercepts of ARIMA model using R

Tags: r

I want to collect the coefficient of the following ARIMA modelling and save in external folder, any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    set.seed(123)
## ARMA(2,2) description for arim.sim()
ARMA22 <- list(order = c(2, 0, 2), ar = c(-0.7, 0.2), ma = c(0.7,
                                                             0.2))
## mean of process
mu <- 5
## simulated process (+ mean)
ARMA.sim <- arima.sim(n = 10000, model = ARMA22) + mu
## estimate parameters
arima(x = ARMA.sim, order = c(2, 0, 2))

## empty list to store model fits
ARMA.res <- list()
## set counter
cc <- 1
## loop over AR
for (p in 0:3) {
  ## loop over MA
  for (q in 0:3) {
    ARMA.res[[cc]] <- arima(x = ARMA.sim, order = c(p, 0, q))
    cc <- cc + 1
  }
}
ARMA.res
```

output:

```
     [[1]]
    
    Call:
    arima(x = ARMA.sim, order = c(p, 0, q))
    
    Coefficients:
          intercept
             4.9975
    s.e.     0.0132
    
    sigma^2 estimated as 1.739:  log likelihood = -16955.58,  aic = 33915.15
    
    [[2]]
    
    Call:
    arima(x = ARMA.sim, order = c(p, 0, q))
    
    Coefficients:
              ma1  intercept
          -0.2106     4.9975
    s.e.   0.0073     0.0100
    
    sigma^2 estimated as 1.602:  log likelihood = -16546.2,  aic = 33098.4
    
    [[3]]
    
    Call:
    arima(x = ARMA.sim, order = c(p, 0, q))
    
    Coefficients:
             ma1     ma2  intercept
          -0.101  0.4002     4.9975
    s.e.   0.011  0.0084     0.0149
    
    sigma^2 estimated as 1.321:  log likelihood = -15581.31,  aic = 31170.62

''''
  
    [[9]]
    
    '''
    [[16]]
```

I want to collect the coefficients and the intercept in the following format and save in the external folder:

```
   intercept ar1  ar2  ma1    ma2 
    4.995   NA   NA  NA      NA
    4.997   NA   NA  -0.2106 NA
    .............................
    ..............................
```

When I use the do.call, it won't give me. Any assistance, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `dplyr::bind_rows()` and `coef()`:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(ARMA.res, coef))
```

```
# A tibble: 16 x 7
   intercept    ma1    ma2     ma3     ar1    ar2     ar3
       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1      5.00 NA     NA     NA      NA      NA     NA     
 2      5.00 -0.211 NA     NA      NA      NA     NA     
 3      5.00 -0.101  0.400 NA      NA      NA     NA     
 4      5.00 -0.104  0.369 -0.262  NA      NA     NA     
 5      5.00 NA     NA     NA      -0.388  NA     NA     
 6      5.00  0.726 NA     NA      -0.953  NA     NA     
 7      5.00  0.867  0.332 NA      -0.903  NA     NA     
 8      5.00  0.904  0.386  0.0723 -0.921  NA     NA     
 9      5.00 NA     NA     NA      -0.191   0.507 NA     
10      5.00  0.482 NA     NA      -0.514   0.392 NA     
11      5.00  0.691  0.200 NA      -0.708   0.192 NA     
12      5.00  0.766  0.266  0.0265 -0.783   0.125 NA     
13      5.00 NA     NA     NA      -0.0477  0.453 -0.283 
14      5.00  0.315 NA     NA      -0.333   0.398 -0.140 
15      5.00  0.660  0.186 NA      -0.677   0.206 -0.0136
16      5.00  0.182 -0.152 -0.102  -0.199   0.553 -0.0972
```

Comment: thanks but I got this error: Error: Argument 1 must have names, after loading necessary packages.

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser Then there is code that you are running that is not present in your question, or else there is an issue with differing software versions. If there is additional code necessary to reproduce your error than is present in your question, please [edit] it to make sure you have a [mcve]. That will help determine a full solution to your problem. If you are *only* running the code from your question and my answer, _in a fresh R session_, and receive that error, please [edit] your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`, which may help diagnose the difference in results.